# Serialize list count instead of list

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I am logging the XML request that is received by the web service in JSON file.
We have a class with all the attributes as follows:

```
class RequestExternal
{
  [XmlAttribute("FirstName")]
  [JsonProperty]
  public string Firstname{get; set;}

  [XmlAttribute("FirstName")]
  [JsonProperty]
  public string LastName{get; set;}

  [XmlAttribute("FirstName")]
  [JsonProperty] -- To be changed : Want to log this as PaymentCards.Count
  public List<Object> PaymentCards{get; set;}
}
```

I want to log this request as:

```
{
  FirstName: 'XXX',
  LastName: 'XXX',
  PaymentCount: **count of PaymentCard list**
}
```

Is there a way to do it via JsonConverter or something?

I can do it by introducing a new derived property.

But that will not work for me. we have a documentation mechanism which will expose those new property to the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending in the specifics of your use case and if you have access to the class definition. You could easily write a *converter* and *annotate* the property

**Given**

```
public class ListToCountConverter : JsonConverter<IList>
{
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, IList value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      => writer.WriteValue(value.Count);

   public override IList ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, IList existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Your Class**

```
class RequestExternal
{
   ...
   [JsonProperty] 
   [JsonConverter(typeof(ListToCountConverter))]
   public List<Object> PaymentCards { get; set; }
}
```

**Example**

```
var test = new RequestExternal()
{
   Firstname = "Bob",
   LastName = "Derp",
   PaymentCards = new List<object>(){null,null,null}
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "Firstname": "Bob",
  "LastName": "Derp",
  "PaymentCards": 3
}
```